# Using the TIBCO EMS Java API, what does calling DestinationInfo.getInboundStatistics().getByteRate() mean by returning -1?

Tags: java, tibco-ems

I am using the TIBCO EMS Java API to get inbound/outbound byte rates and message rates for TopicInfo and QueueInfo.

I am using functions defined in [DestinationInfo](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/8.1.0/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/admin/DestinationInfo.html): getInboundStatistics and getOutboundStatistics. These return a value of type [StatData](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/8.1.0/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/com/tibco/tibjms/admin/StatData.html):

As it is, if there are no messages, these rates are returning -1. I was expecting that byte/message rates would both be 0. Does anyone have any idea why -1 is returned instead?

I'm assuming that this is to differentiate having no messages and having rate collection turned off, but there doesn't seem to be documentations indicating the reason for the -1.

Comment: Have you try using [TIBCO GEMS](https://tibcobwblog.com/2013/03/08/graphical-ems-administration-tool/comment-page-1/) a free GUI to browse and visualize TIBCO EMS configuration. Just want to check if you've got the same weird value otherwise it could be a bug in Java Library.

Comment: The client mentioned that it matched, so looks like that's how it should be. Thanks for the tip